# Register routes assigned with Attribute Routing at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, runtime, attributerouting

I am working on the MVC application that loads controller at runtime from an external assembly with MEF and registers routes using custom route handler I have implemented with help of this tutorial:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx/

However recently I discovered a powerful features in MVC 5.1, called Attribute Routing.
I would like to know if that is possible to create a custom Attribute Routing that registers Attribute Routing at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No. This method basically just turns `RouteConfig.cs` into a runtime-compiled assembly instead of something that's pre-built by the time your application runs. Frankly, I think that is just about one of the most horrible ideas ever. I give credit to the author for being clever enough to figure out how to do something like that. It's a wonderful thought exercise, but as production code: *OMFG, no way*.

With Attribute Routing, all your routes are in your controllers, so to do the same thing would require making all your controllers individual runtime-compiled assemblies, and that goes beyond scary. Don't do that.